# safety regarding running ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, vmware-workstation

I am new to Linux. before installing it i want to know something 
is it safe if I run Ubuntu on VMware on my original windows 10.
will it do any harm to my windows if i run it on this virtual platform rather than going for partitioning my disk.

UPD: while installing Ubuntu I got this error what should I do now?

This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.

Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.

(1) Verify that the BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and disable 'trusted execution.'

(2) Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings have been changed.

(3) Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing VMware Player.

(4) Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the latest version.

This host does not support "Intel EPT" hardware assisted MMU virtualization.

Module 'CPUIDEarly' power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine.

Comment: These problems arise when running 64 bit virtual machines if you have not enabled virtualization in your BIOS/UEFI settings. Every manufacturer is different so I can't tell you how to do it.

Comment: ok thanks .  just got it,  change BIOS settings which we can see while the computer is starting press F10 9 or 10 times and there we'll get the options to enable Intel VT-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 thing to consider: If your Windows is hacked someone can use a cryptolocker to lock your Ubuntu container. A dual boot would prevent that. With dual boot your Windows and your Ubuntu need to be broken and not just main OS.

If anything I would try to set up the system with Ubuntu as a host and Windows as virtual. Use a good password and backup as often as needed.

> is it safe if I run Ubuntu on VMware on my original windows 10. will it do any harm to my windows

Yes, it is safe. The OS itself can not even see the host OS. If anything breaks it is more likely by your actions than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

NO, it won't harm your OS(Windows OS) though you require atleast 1 GB RAM space free to run UBUNTU in a Virtual machine. Else you can try UBUNTU without installing, Just burn the iso file of UBUNTU in a Flash drive(use [RUFUS](https://rufus.akeo.ie/)) to make it bootable and try before you install.